# Do node.js domains automatically clean themselves up or do I have to call domain.dispose()

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, node.js-domains

I'm a bit confused about [node.js domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). I'm using them to catch errors that may be thrown in asynchronous code.

I'm not sure though, whether or not domains automatically clean themselves up for garbage collection once the `domain.run(blah)` has finished, or wether or not I have to manually call `domain.dispose()` once I am done with the domain?

The problem with `domain.dispose()` is that it also destroys all io streams that the domain may have been intercepting, which is not what I want as I'm just using this particular domain to just catch thrown errors in asynchronous code.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/UCqbgxI8gRw seems to have some info but not enough to give a clear answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use it, it will be deprecated: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5018

Comment: Just in case someone else misreads this, as I did at first glance, it's the "dispose" method of domains that is being deprecated, not domains themselves.